# Python - Selenium get Element by attribute and the full attribute value

Tags: python, selenium

Hi how can I get an element by `attribute and the attribute value` in **Python** **Selenium**?

For example I have `class="class1 class2 class3".`

Now I want to get the element with the attribute class what `ca.rries` the classes `"class1 class2 class3".`

Is this possible?

If I use xpath, I always need to add the `element type, input, option,...`
I try to avoid the element type since it varies sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

While constructing [*locators*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120) considering [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) or [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) you have to use the different *attributes* and the *attribute-values* to identify the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) uniquely within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes).

The generic way is:

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  button.classname[attributeA='attributeA_value'][attributeB='attributeB_value']
  ```
- Using *xpath* and attributes:

  ```
  //button[@attributeA='attributeA_value'][@attributeB='attributeB_value']
  ```

As an example, for an element like:

```
<button type="button" aria-hidden="true" class="close alert alert-close" data-notify="dismiss">Close</button>
```

You can identify the <kbd>Close</kbd> element using either of it's the *attributes* and the corresponding *attribute-values* using either of the [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  button.close.alert.alert-close[data-notify='dismiss']
  classes-> ^   ^^    ^^^        data-notify ^^^^ attribute
  ```
- Using *xpath* and attributes:

  ```
  //button[@class='close alert alert-close' and @data-notify='dismiss']
   class attributes  ^    ^^     ^^^             data-notify ^^^^ attribute
  ```
- Using *xpath* and innerText:

  ```
  //button[text()='Close']
         innerText ^
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selectors would be formatted like this:

`'[attribute]'`

`'[attribute="value"]'`

For example, the selector for the input field on google.com would be:

`'input[name="q"]'`

Comment: thx. 
This means I can get the element like this:
[class="class1 class2 class3"]
However I still need to define an element type like input, div, textarea,...
Is there an option where I do not need to add an element type?
This would be helpful since I have various element types.

Comment: Both ``'input[name="q"]'`` and ``'[name="q"]'`` would be valid selectors.

Answer (score 0):

to answer this part

> If I use xpath, I always need to add the element type, input,
> option,... I try to avoid the element type since it varies sometimes.

you can use `//*` and then attribute type and attribute value.

```
//*[@class='class1 class2 class3']
```

**//*** represent **any** or **all nodes**